# Не запускается open server, ошибка в php

Tags: php, openserver

Установил Open Server, для проверки создал в папке domains папку test.ru с файлом index.php там обычный код

```
<? php 
echo "<h1>hi</h1>";
?>
```

когда открываю через сервер пишет это
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\OSPanel\domains\test.ru\index.php on line 2

Comment: Такая же проблема, но пробела нет... Какие еще варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробела после `<?` не должно быть, вот так попробуйте

```
<?php 
echo "<h1>hi</h1>";
?>
```

2 варианта объявления php кода в файле
`<?` и `<?php`
и `<?=` для вывода значений в `html`

Comment: Учитывая что это PHP файл, то в конце можно не закрывать "?>"
А так да, ответ верный, у автора пробел

Comment: Спасибо, проблема все таки была в пробеле после знака вопроса)

Comment: @РоманРомашко если Вас устраивает ответ, поставьте галочку рядом с ним